# Parsing JSON array a few levels deep in php

Tags: php, json, jenkins

I am pretty new to json and arrays and I have the following but I am not getting any results from a Jenkins JSON output.

Link to output - http://resonant-rise.com/mcupdater/parser.php

Code

```
$url = "http://jenkins.jakimfett.com/job/AlchemyPlusPlus/lastSuccessfulBuild/api/json?pretty=true";
$output = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
print "<pre>";
print_r($output);
print "</pre>";

foreach ($output->actions as $item) {
    echo $item->fullDisplayName . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
$url="http://jenkins.jakimfett.com/job/AlchemyPlusPlus/lastSuccessfulBuild/api/json?pretty=true"; 
$output = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true); 
echo "<pre>";
print_r($output);
echo "</pre>";

/* for properties like fullDisplayName, id, keeplog etc .. directly use echo */
echo $output['fullDisplayName'];

/* for properties like actions and artifacts */
foreach($output['actions'] as $action){
    print_r($action);   /* actions itself is array so use print_r */
}
?>
```